# Upload Files to S3 Bucket without using access key and secret key in Node Js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Although I am able to upload file to s3 bucket by using access key and secret key.
AND
I am trying to upload a file to AWS s3 bucket without using access key and secret key. Please assist me.
Here is my code,

```
import {path} from "path";

const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: 'Region'});

// Enter copied or downloaded access ID and secret key here
const ID = 'id';
const SECRET = 'id';

// The name of the bucket that you have created
const BUCKET_NAME = 'name';

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
     accessKeyId: ID,
     secretAccessKey: SECRET
 });

const FILE_PATH = 'filepath';



const uploadFile = (fileName) => {
    // Read content from the file
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName);

    // Setting up S3 upload parameters
    const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: path.basename(FILE_PATH), // File name you want to save as in S3
        Body: fileContent
    };

    // Uploading files to the bucket
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}');
    });
};

uploadFile(FILE_PATH);
```

Comment: Where would the AWS credentails come from if not from your access and secret keys?

Comment: the question you are asking is not clear to me maybe due to I am a fresher. Simply what I need is using nodejs, I should able to upload a file to s3 bucket! (without access key and secret key)

Comment: Is it possible to do so by adding a IAM role with giving full s3 access? if so could you please help me with that?

Comment: Need more details. Where is your app hosted? Lambda? EC2? Local?

Comment: I have used a EC2

Comment: @Marcin I am getting the access key and secret key from EC2. I have created a user role by granting s3 all access.

Comment: @LahiruFerreira AWS sdk automatically checks for instance roles. So you don't have to do it explicitly in your code.

Comment: @marcin Can you please give some documentation links or any blog links regarding this from the beginning? That would be very helpful!

Comment: How did it go? The link provided is not clear?

Comment: @Marcin I went through the link but it still asks for the created user's  credentials. could you please let me know, is there any way to identify the s3 bucket with the name of the bucket or user roll( without any secret or access key)?

Comment: I found a solution but I am not sure whether it is 100% correct or not.
I can access the s3 bucket by creating a cognito identity pool. we can pass that pool id in our code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way we can upload files into s3 bucket without using any access key or secret key. You can create a congnito pool id in AWS.

So my problem was how can I upload a file to s3 bucket without using access key and secret key...

Below I have written the Solution for my problem

```
private async uploadFile(fileName: string) {
        CustomLogger.logger.info('Inside File Upload Method');
        
        AWS.config.region = 'ADD YOUR REGION';
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'ADD YOUR COGNITO ID'
        });

        const BUCKET_NAME = 'ADD YOUR BUCKET NAME';

        const s3 = new AWS.S3({
            region: AWS.config.region,
            credentials: AWS.config.credentials
        });

        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName);

        const params = {
            Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: LpServiceImpl.getZipFileName(fileName),
            Body: fileContent
        };

        s3.upload(params, (err: Error, data: any) => {
            if (err) {
                CustomLogger.logger.info('File upload failed.');
                throw err;
            }

           

            CustomLogger.logger.info('File uploaded successfully.' + data.Location);

        });
    };

    private static getZipFileName(filePath: string){
        const n = filePath.split("\\");
        CustomLogger.logger.info('Split Successfully');
        return n[n.length - 1];
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @Tyler2P I have edited the answer with a small explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The use of credentails from instance role in SDK for JavaScript is explained in:

- [Loading credentials in Node.js from IAM roles for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-iam.html)

> the SDK **automatically** selects the IAM credentials for your application, eliminating the need to manually provide credentials.

Comment: I've been using that for a while, but I was wondering if it's possible to do something similar from a development environment?

Comment: @WayneSmallman Why not make a dedicated question for that?